# Why is the netcat response not displaying in browser in Mac OS?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, netcat

I've tried using netcat in various ways.

1. The common just exits
   `echo "Response from server"  | nc  -l 127.0.0.1 8080`
2. I get the following error in browser `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

`nc -l localhost 8080 < temp.resp`

I just simply want to print some text from nectar to browser and maybe later pass some headers along with it too. But right now I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

I've looked in the man page and tried -w and -I options but none of them are working.

Comment: You have a typo in your title: you meant "mac OS" instead of "max OS".

Comment: You need the headers, otherwise this is not a valid HTTP response

Comment: @thatotherguy. I tried it in linux openSuse, there was no need of headers and was working fine . temp.resp file contains "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" which should be enough ryt ?

Comment: That should be enough to give you a blank page, yes. It works for me in Chrome on macOS. Writing `Response from server` instead gives me a connection refused message. I'm seeing that Safari for some reason connects and disconnects once first, so if that's your browser you can put your command in a loop.

Comment: Yeah. I am facing the same thing. I am getting a blank page in chrome. Safari disconnects before the conman is executed it seems . I’ll stick to chrome for now but how do I write response to chrome from netcat ? I mean more than just headers .

Comment: I don't recommend using netcat for this at all. If you want something that can have a single instance handle as many inbound connections as need be (spawning a separate subprocess to generate output for each incoming connection), look at [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). Though I'm not sure that's your problem -- `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means, well, that it couldn't connect. Often that's a firewall issue; MacOS prompts for whether to allow a connection to open listening sockets whenever something first tries, if disallowed, there may be work you need to do to make it ask again.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy unfortunately I don't have that option. I've to use netcat only.